# How to make Flow understand dynamic code that uses lodash for runtime type-checking?

Tags: flowtype

Flow's [dynamic code example](https://flowtype.org/docs/five-simple-examples.html#dynamic-code) indicates that Flow can figure out runtime type-checking:

```js
function foo(x) {
  if (typeof x === 'string') {
    return x.length; // flow is smart enough to see this is safe
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}

var res = foo('Hello') + foo(42);
```

But in real life, `typeof` isn't good enough. I usually use lodash's  type-checking functions (`_.isFunction`, `_.isString` etc), which handle a lot of edge cases.

The problem is, if we change the example to use lodash for the runtime type-checking, Flow no longer understands it:

```js
function foo(x) {
  if (_.isString(x)) {
    return x.length; // warning: `length` property not found in Number
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}

var res = foo('Hello') + foo(42);
```

I tried using [iflow-lodash](https://github.com/marudor/flowInterfaces) but it doesn't seem to make a difference here.

What's the best solution to make Flow understand code that uses lodash for runtime type-checking? I'm new to Flow btw.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would depend on having predicate types in your lodash libdefs.

Predicate types have recently been added to Flow. Although they are still in an experimental state so I would recommend being careful about their usage for anything serious for now.

```js
function isString(x): boolean %checks { // << declare that the method is a refinement
  return typeof x === 'string';
}

function method(x: string | number): number {
  if (isString(x)) { // << valid refinement
    return x.charCodeAt(0); // << no errors
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}
```

[[try it out](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5sxCBnAZXwCdDsBzACgA8BKALjACM44YApgENSAUlwALAbgDW5MAG9UYMDQH5MNUvgCeABwFwoYFmAC8FsAHJytegysBuVAF90WPERJgAtuolwACasXLZ0jGAAPmDYmD7cAjScMXEJNIrKZMZMFNThzOxsGSoqahpaJgB0kkI0AMJBAgCC+EwADGzOKi5gAjDkAsUlZZqkLF1gbi5AA)]

> **Note:** This answer may quickly fall out of date in one of the next releases as this is a brand new feature. Check out Flow's [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/Changelog.md) for the latest information.

The solution for now if possible is to use [the built-in refinements](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html).

```js
function method(x: string | number): number {
  if (typeof x === "string") { // << Inline the check
    return x.charCodeAt(0);
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution for this specific case is:

```
if (_.isString(x) && typeof x === 'string') {
```

In general, you might be able to overcome Flow errors with creative error suppression, like this:

```
if (_.isString(x)) {
  // @ManuallyTyped
  var xStr: string = x;
  return xStr.length;
} else { ... }
```

Make sure to define `// @ManuallyTyped` as a custom `suppress_comment` in your flow config file for this to work. You might need an ugly regex for that, see flow docs.

It's been a while since I've last done this, but if I recall correctly Flow will **assume** that your `xStr` is a `string`, while the rest of type checking will work just fine.

Comment: `ManuallyTyped` is not a thing.

Comment: @Hristo You _make_ it a thing by defining it in `suppress_comment` in your `.flowconfig`. Can choose any other name just as well. See https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex